# Можно ли поставить тире в предложении:

Tags: пунктуация

Пройдёт время (?) он не вернётся.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Постановка тире зависит от смысла:

**Пройдёт время — он не вернётся.** Значение : Если пройдет время...

**Продет время, но он не вернется.** При противопоставлении нужен  союз и запятая.

Comment: Здравствуйте. А если смысл таков: Когда пройдёт время?

Comment: Союзы КОГДА и ЕСЛИ по смыслу бывают  взаимозаменяемыми, поэтому это первый вариант с тире и со значением "когда пройдет время, в том случае если пройдет время".